# Form submit results in "Too many redirects" error for anonymous users

Tags: 8, forms, routes

I have a custom route on my site at `/search`. This page has a couple of forms on it (defined with FormBase).

When I am logged in, the form appears to work.

When I am anonymous, many many requests occur when I submit and causes a "too many redirects" error in the browser.

Here is my routing.yml

```
mymodule.search:
 path: '/search'
 defaults:
   _title_callback: 'Drupal\mymodule\Controller\SearchPage::title'
   _controller: 'Drupal\mymodule\Controller\SearchPage::build'
 requirements:
   _permission: 'access content'
```

Here is one of the forms:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode;

/**
 * Class KeywordForm.
 *
 * @package Drupal\mymodule\Form
 */
class KeywordForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack definition.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack
   */
  protected $requestStack;

  /**
   * Constructor for our class.
   */
  public function __construct(RequestStack $request_stack) {
    $this->requestStack = $request_stack;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('request_stack')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'iana_keyword_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $keywords = Xss::filter($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('keywords'));
    $site_ids = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('site_id');
    $sort_by = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('sort_by');
    $sort_order = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('sort_order');

    $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'search-result__form';

    if (!is_array($site_ids)) {
      $site_ids = [];
    }

    $form['keywords'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#cache' => ['contexts' => ['url.query_args:keywords']],
      '#default_value' => Unicode::strlen($keywords) ? $keywords : '',
      '#prefix' => '<div class="search-box__input js-search-input">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#attributes' => [
        'placeholder' => Unicode::strlen($keywords) ? $keywords : t('Search for...'),
      ],
    ];

    $form['site_id'] = [
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#value' => $site_ids,
    ];

    $form['sort_by'] = [
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#value' => $sort_by,
    ];

    $form['sort_order'] = [
      '#type' => 'hidden',
      '#value' => $sort_order,
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Search'),
      '#attributes' => [
        'class' => [
          'search-box__button',
        ],
        'data-twig-suggestion' => 'search_results_submit',
      ],
    ];

    $form['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'session';
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->setRedirect(
      'mymodule.search',
      [
        'keywords' => $form_state->getValue('keywords'),
        'site_id' => $form_state->getValue('site_id'),
        'sort_by' => $form_state->getValue('sort_by'),
        'sort_order' => $form_state->getValue('sort_order'),
      ],
      [
        'query' => [
          'keywords' => $form_state->getValue('keywords'),
          'site_id' => $form_state->getValue('site_id'),
          'sort_by' => $form_state->getValue('sort_by'),
          'sort_order' => $form_state->getValue('sort_order'),
        ],
      ]
    );
  }

}
```

It looks like at some point, I hit this bit of code in the FormBuilder class:

```
// If the form returns a response, skip subsequent page construction by
// throwing an exception.
// @see Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EnforcedFormResponseSubscriber
//
// @todo Exceptions should not be used for code flow control. However, the
//   Form API does not integrate with the HTTP Kernel based architecture of
//   Drupal 8. In order to resolve this issue properly it is necessary to
//   completely separate form submission from rendering.
//   @see https://www.drupal.org/node/2367555
if ($response instanceof Response) {
  throw new EnforcedResponseException($response);
}
```

Here is what Google Chrome devtools window shows for network activity:

[image]

What is going on here, and how can I fix this? I need the values attached to the URL when the form is submitted.

All of the Forms are displayed on the sidebar and header as blocks injecting those forms. Only 3 forms exist, keyword and a simple checkbox filter.

For the life of me, I can't see what is wrong.

The cache_render table is filling up with various search URLs, it should not, though no matter what I set #cache to, it does.

Comment: Do you have the module Redirect installed?

Comment: Yes, I do. I looked to see if there were redirects from search, I did not see any.

Comment: No, this is about the global redirect settings, disable all of the seven options and test again, there is an issue concerning anonymous traffic.

Comment: I will try that. Is the use of setRedirect in this manner now discouraged? It used to work in D7.

Comment: setRedirect is not the problem, but you can get a problem how the Redirect module handles the resulting redirect response.

Comment: So the forms on `/search` work when I add `/search*` as "pages to ignore" under Redirect. Checking now with all seven options unchecked. The _one_ form that still causes infinite redirects is a keyword search in the header that is on every page, that posts to `/search`.

Comment: In conjunction with adding the search url to ignore, THIS is the option that was causing the issue for anonymous: "Enforce clean and canonical URLs.". Unchecking that, clearing cache, all forms work from anywhere now. The other options are still enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to 4k4 and some folks in IRC, it turns out that the culprit here is the Redirect module.

I was able to solve this by:

- Disable `Enforce clean and canonical URLs.` in Redirect
- Add `/search` and `/search*` to URLs to ignore in Redirect

After setting that and clearing cache, anonymous users were no longer stuck in an endless redirect loop when using search forms.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this. that you add your route with both route parameters and query arguments for the same is weird and shouldhn't be necessary. Not sure how you ignored the URL's, but the ignore in the settings is just about 404 logging and has nothing to do with redirects. If there really is no other way, you could opt out of the clean feature by setting an option on your route, check the redirect request subscriber. But that should only be necessary in case of weird request processing like private files